# PrimeFaces p:fileUpload upload multiple files on submit

Tags: jsf, primefaces, upload

I need to upload multiple files, but I need to upload them all together then the "submit" button is clicked (that either ALL files are stored, or nothing).

How can I achieve this? 
And how can I get a list of files which I uploaded?

here is my code:

```
<h:form>
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{bean.moveFile}" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"  mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true" multiple="true"  />  
    <h:commandButton value="Speichern" action="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Primefaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadMultiple.jsf). The `handleFileUpload` method gets called for every uploaded file. If you want to have a list of uploaded files, just store them in an adequate data structure.

If you need to know *how* to store a specific uploaded file, read these articles:

1.) [j2ee primefaces fileupload file saving destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358493/j2ee-primefaces-fileupload-file-saving-destination)

2.) [How to Upload a file using JSF/Primefaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9515776/1731935)

3.) [Where does p:fileUpload save my file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666370/where-does-pfileupload-save-my-file)

Comment: So do I need to create my own custom list to view all already uploaded files? what happens to the uploaded files, when the windows is closed? are they deleted?

Comment: Yes. If you dont store the files within the `moveFile` method, the files won't be stored. I think they are just a temporary object and live as long until the request is processed. SO, store your files to the harddrive, database or somewhere else before they are lost.